# Changing the date format in a Materialize date picker modal

Tags: javascript, datepicker, materialize

Changing the format inside the text field works perfectly fine, but I was unable to figure out how to change the format inside the modal to 'dd.mm.yyyy'. How can I do this?

[This is where I want to change the format.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M1CgM.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read the [SO guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to ask a good question. Try adding a little bit of code so we can see how did you implement this.

Answer (score 0):

Open your materialize.js and look for this code:

```
    key: "_renderDateDisplay",
    value: function _renderDateDisplay() {
       var displayDate = Datepicker._isDate(this.date) ? this.date : new Date();
       var i18n = this.options.i18n;
       var day = i18n.weekdaysShort[displayDate.getDay()];
       var month = i18n.months[displayDate.getMonth()];
       var date = displayDate.getDate();
      this.yearTextEl.innerHTML = displayDate.getFullYear();
      this.dateTextEl.innerHTML = day + ", " + date + " " + month;
    }
```

here you can change the order of the format and the type of the date, I mean for example `weekdaysShort` to `weekdays` etc.